# Complex old site URL redirect (301) with query string not working (WordPress site)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a strange situation that I'm struggling to solve, I've done 301 redirects loads of times before, but this ones got me stumped and I'm struggling to find anything useful on stack overflow of similar (I really have tried!)

I have a new site live, the URL structure is completely different to the old site structure (the new site is built on WordPress with permalinks on with the usual htaccess rewrite rules).

There is no pattern or association with the URL's to re-use - I just want a hard redirect from old URL to new URL.

I think it's either the .asp part that's screwing things up, or the query var maybe - I've tried a-lot of different things and am not having any luck - I'd really appreciate some help on this!

Here is what obviously didn't work:

```
Redirect 301 /info/index.asp?page=a-string-here https://newsite.com/new-page-link/
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Old URL example:**

```
/info/index.asp?page=a-string-here
```

**New URL example**

```
/something-completely-different
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pages are only ever defined by the 'page' querystring variable, then you can use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=a-string-here
RewriteRule .*$ /something-completely-different? [L,R=301]
```

If not let me know a bit more about the structure of the old URLs.

> Notes:
>   - A single `?` is appended to the substitution string to strip the existing querystring from it. If you want to keep the old querstring, i.e. `/something-completely-different?page=a-string-here`, then delete the `?`.
>   - If you want to add new query string data you can add it as you would naturally, after a `?` like so: `/something-completely-different?new=var`
>   - And finally, to add new vars while retaining the old ones, add the `QSA` flag to the RewriteRule flags. i.e `[QSA, L,R=301]`
>   *([Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))*

Comment: **NICE** - thanks - and for the notes too!! I'll give that a test - there are some other pages but they don't have the page query param, so I shouldn't have a problem with those ;)

Comment: **YES!** Thanks - that has worked perfectly - marked as accepted, you are a gentleman and a scholar!